# Luis Microsoft Bot Framework BadArgument: prebuilt models

Tags: bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm creating a bot where I can ask a specific temperature of a room. I've build something custom where I can read the temperature of my room. But when I build an hierarchical entity where I put the word temperature in, it refuses to use the word because LUIS use it in an prebuilt model.

Is there a way i can use the word?

> BadArgument: The name temperature is reserved to prebuilt models.
>   Please use another name

[image]

Comment: Is there a valid reason that the word temperature must be used?  I suggest using a different word, like: "temp" or "climate" or "degrees".

Comment: Yes, the whole project has to be around air quality. So the best word would be "temperature".

Comment: Temperature is a keword in LUIS.  Just like when you are programming, you cannot use some variable names because they are keywords in the language.  You'll have to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an entity called `temperature` because the name is already taken by the prebuilt one. However, @Eric's argument is valid - the name of the entity doesn't affect your application at all, it's just a familiar name to be used by programmers which are using your LUIS app. Consider calling it `temp` or so, and look for the same name in the code using LUIS.